# Django Postgres makemigrations only Autofield at 0001_initial.py

Tags: django, postgresql, makemigrations

Python 3.10.4
Django 4.0.5
PostgreSQL 14

When I start "python manage.py makemigrations" i got the file "0001_initial.py" but all Fields, except autofields, are missing.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Username(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username: models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Carrier(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    carriername: models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc: models.TextField()
```

**0001_initial.py**

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.5 on 2022-06-29 13:18

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Carrier',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Username',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: You have a spelling mistake, define your model fields with `=` not `:` - `username = models.CharField(max_length=100)` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must know that Django By default adds the `id` field to the models ...
Try to Delete the migration file and
you must use the `=`  not the `:`
so it will be like this

```py
class Username(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Carrier(models.Model):
    carriername = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc =  models.TextField()
```

rerun `manage.py makemigrations` and it Should work